# Java copying file from my /bin file to C:/?

Tags: src

so basically I'm really confused and I have a file in my package (miner/bin/s.bin) & how would I get around to copying & moving it to c:/?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/26o82l isn't it just supposed to be String, String? Am I missing something?

Comment: You used the method incorrectly, check the error message...

Comment: Path FROM = Paths.get // how would i get the path of the file in my /bin/ directory of the project?
      Path TO = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\to.txt");
   try {
    Files.copy(FROM, TO);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }